# SQL Selecting a column based on location reference to another column

Tags: sql, excel, select

I have an excel document where some of the columns are not named. The way the excel is organized is that each category has a `DateTime` and a value but only the `DateTime` column has a header (which is the name of the category rather than "date")

for example

```
|Category 1|     | |Category 2|      |
|May 1     |13246| |May 4     |84563 |
|May 3     |65842| |May 7     |84535 |
|May 8     |86453| |May 8     |876541|
```

and etc for the rest of the document. Is there a way I can associate the two columns together with SQL? Possibly something like

```
 Select Category1, [Category1 + 1]
 from Table
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have explored this problem a bit. I think the easiest solution would be to simply add headers.

But a workaround from within VBA. When we create the connection we set HDR = no. This will auto-generate headers for us, F1 through Fn. Unfortunately we will now have a row that reads category 1, null, category 2, null. We cannot run delete queries as they are not supported. I tried to update set that entire row to null but ran into issues.

```
Sub main()
Dim cn                      As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs                      As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strFile                 As String
Dim strCon                  As String
Dim strSql                  As String

    cn.Open _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;"";"

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    cn.Open strCon

    strSql = "SELECT * From [DataTable]"

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    rs.Open strSql, cn

    Debug.Print rs.GetString

    rs.Close

    strSql = "SELECT CDATE([F1]),CDATE([F3]),[F4] FROM [DATATABLE] WHERE [F2] = 13246 ORDER BY [F1];"

    rs.Open strSql, cn

    Debug.Print rs.GetString

    Set cn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

> My Output. First debug.print gets us the entire record set. Then I run a test query and sure enough it looks OK.

```
category 1      category 2  
43221   13246   43224   84563
43223   65842   43227   84535
43228   86453   43228   876541

5/1/2018    5/4/2018    84563
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! I'll try to make it work like this.